# prevent drupal from redirecting to created nodes

Tags: 6, theming, nodes

as you know after publishing a node Drupal redirects to that node. How Can I change this functionality ? I want to force it to stay on the same page or maybe redirect it admin page instead of nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rules to achieve this easily, here:

Add a new rule and give it a name.

**Event:**

After saving new content

**Conditions:**

Content is of type - and chose your content type you want this rule to react on.

**Actions:**

Page redirect - and enter your destination.

here is an export of a rule that will redirect to homepage after insert a new node of type article.

```
{ "rules_test" : {
    "LABEL" : "test",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "node_insert" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "article" : "article" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "\u003Cfront\u003E" } } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you need additional help. :)